# MVC 3 application on IIS 6.0: Unable to read AppSettings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

We have deployed our Asp.Net MVC 3 application on IIS 6.0 on production. We have configured the website using the following article. 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

We have also tried to update the dev.config and web.config to have the "build action" to "none" instead of "content" but to no avail.

The system is unable to read the AppSettings from the file configured in web application. It seems to show only one "WebPostTimeOut" appSettings(I don't know where that is coming from).

***Web.config snippet:***

```
<appSettings file="dev.config"/>
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="domainname\_webuser" password="_webuser"/>
</system.web>
```

***dev.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="XcacheDataPath" value="c:\cf_web\xcache_datafiles\!eol"/>
  <add key="CacheExpiration" value="120"/>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Any ideas on what could we be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running aspnet_iisreg.  See if there are any errors in the log files.  Correct those errors.  Either your process ID doesn't have permissions to the file, the file doesn't exist, or the folder for the web site doesn't exist.